# Merge two datasets based on date ranges. R

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table, date-range

My goal is to merge two datasets using date ranges. Dataset1 contains patients stays in a hospital overtime. Dataset2 contains room information overtime. My goal is to identify what type of room the stays were in my Dataset1. It can get complicated since room type in some hospitalizations can change. For example patient 101 second hospitalization was part ICU and part Emergency.

Dataset 1:

```
  PatientID Hospital Room           StartDate             EndDate
1       101     ODCC  4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39
2       101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34
3       101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-10-02 06:50:24
4       101     ODCC   1W 2020-10-02 06:50:25 2020-10-05 14:25:54
```

Dataset 2:

```
  Hospital Room      Type    StartDT      EndDT
1     ODCC  11A     Other 2020-01-01 2021-05-12
2     ODCC   1W       ICU 2020-06-01 2020-07-30
3     ODCC   1W Emergency 2020-08-01 2021-05-12
4     ODCC   1N Emergency 2020-11-05 2021-02-07
```

My goal:

```
  Patient.ID Hospital Room           StartDate             EndDate      Type    StartDT      EndDT
1        101     ODCC  4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2        101     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34       ICU 2020-06-01 2020-07-30
3        102     ODCC   1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34 Emergency 2020-08-01 2021-05-12
4        101     ODCC   1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-10-02 06:50:24      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5        101     ODCC   1W 2020-10-02 06:50:25 2020-10-05 14:25:54 Emergency 2020-08-01 2021-05-12
```

Below you can find codes to replicate my datasets.

```
stays <- structure(list(
  PatientID = c(101, 101, 101, 101),
  Hospital = c("ODCC", "ODCC", "ODCC", "ODCC"),
  Room = c("4SW", "1W", "1N", "1W"), 
  StartDate = structure(c(1591287707, 1592838760, 1599573815, 1601621425),
                        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
  EndDate = structure(c(1592838759, 1599573814, 1601621424, 1601907954), 
                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

type <- structure(list(
  Hospital = c("ODCC", "ODCC", "ODCC", "ODCC"), 
  Room = c("11A", "1W", "1W", "1N"), Type = c("Other", "ICU", "Emergency",
                                              "Emergency"), 
  StartDT = structure(c(1577836800, 1590969600, 1596240000, 1604534400), 
                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
  EndDT = structure(c(1620777600, 1596067200, 1620777600, 1612656000),
                    class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `foverlaps`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stays)
setDT(type)
setkey(type,Hospital,Room,StartDT,EndDT)
foverlaps(stays,type,
          by.x=c("Hospital","Room","StartDate","EndDate"),
          by.y=c("Hospital","Room","StartDT","EndDT"),type="any")[
            ,.(
              PatientID,
              Hospital,
              Room,
              StartDate,
              EndDate,
              Type,
              StartDT,
              EndDT)]       

   PatientID Hospital   Room           StartDate             EndDate      Type    StartDT      EndDT
       <num>   <char> <char>              <POSc>              <POSc>    <char>     <POSc>     <POSc>
1:       101     ODCC    4SW 2020-06-04 16:21:47 2020-06-22 15:12:39      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2:       101     ODCC     1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34       ICU 2020-06-01 2020-07-30
3:       101     ODCC     1W 2020-06-22 15:12:40 2020-09-08 14:03:34 Emergency 2020-08-01 2021-05-12
4:       101     ODCC     1N 2020-09-08 14:03:35 2020-10-02 06:50:24      <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
5:       101     ODCC     1W 2020-10-02 06:50:25 2020-10-05 14:25:54 Emergency 2020-08-01 2021-05-12
```

Comment: I got the following error: Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”. Does it have to do with the date format of my type data? Did you get the same error? Thank you!

Comment: As you had `data.table` in tags, I forgot to start my answer with `library(data.table)` (see my edit). The code works then without problem on my system. Do you get the error with the example dataset, or with more data?

Comment: I reinstalled the data.table package and it works now.  I will explore forlaps in more detail to understand what the code is doing. I got some issues with my real dataset since some Startdates are greater than Enddates. I will fix this and the code should work. Thank you so much, this is great!

Comment: I am sorry to get back to this post. I have a question. Why you didn't include the hospital variable as a key? In my real data, sometimes different hospitals has the same Room name. Will this be an issue? Also, the final data is missing the hospital name for the first and last row. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're right, added Hospital to the key. I have to look more in detail to understand why some overlaps aren't found nad return NA.